# Transfer user profile from Vista x64 to Windows 7 x86?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, migration

How can I transfer user profiles from Vista x64 to Windows 7 x86?
If I try to start the migwiz from Windows 7 x86 on the Vista x64 machine, it complains about the wrong architecture.

Comment: it isn't supported with usmt, or any other tool i know of...if it must be done you could try editing the windows version string to be x86 and see if you get lucky....best of luck

Comment: Wow, aking1012, that's a brave suggestion. Stranger things have happened though: I edited that same string to "upgrade" an illegal Ultimate version to a legal Home Premium, so I guess it's worth a shot. +1 for the sheer audacity of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your risk here is that the architecture **is** different, and therefore if you had 64-bit DLLs and executables migrated over, they won't work, and instead of fielding calls of "the stupid thing doesn't work", Microsoft won't support it in the first place.

I don't think it's possible through any conventional methods. Why are you migrating to 32-bit Windows 7 anyway? What is stopping you from going to 64-bit?

Comment: I had x64 Vista to use all of my RAM. But an essential Software (Beckhoff Twincat 2.0) doesn't support x64, so I must use x86.

Comment: Yeesh, normally I'd suggest virtualising Windows XP inside a Windows 7 machine, but it looks like this TwinCAT needs to be closer to the hardware than through a virtual machine.

Comment: Yes, that's it ;)